# Define array capacity in number of bytes in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, memory-management

A program I am working on is doing some string manipulation in which the output array containing the words will be the same or smaller than the input array.  For example, the input array contains 100 elements, each element is one word (varrying length).  After manipulation, there were only be 99 elements.  Let's say the input array is 500 bytes.  Can I tell Swift to make sure the output array is at least 500 bytes long so that when adding elements it doesn't need to move them to a different part of memory with more room for elements multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a misconception. An `Array` stores values of some type `T`, and each of
these values has the same size. In your case, an array of type `[String]` holds values
of type `struct String` which have a fixed size (like values of any type in Swift).

How strings manage to hold a variable number of characters in an implementation detail.
If you examine the Swift source code then you'll see that `struct String` contains
a pointer to the actual string storage (which is reference counted to implement
value semantics with copy-on-write).

So you can reserve space for a given *number of elements* to avoid array
reallocations when elements are added:

```
var words: [String] = []
words.reserveCapacity(100)
```

You also can reserve space in a string's underlying storage to avoid reallocations
if the string is extended:

```
var word = ""
word.reserveSpace(1000)
```

But you don't reserve capacity in an array to hold the total number
of characters of its string elements.

Comment: Yea I realized the mistake I made in the question is about fixed length characters instead of variable length strings.  Woops.

Comment: @traisjames: I think you are mixing different things now. The array stores elements of type `String`, which is a fixed-length structure. Each `String` uses an (opaque) buffer to hold a (possibly varying) number of characters. It is not the array which needs the capacity for the total number of characters.

Comment: @Martain R: oh, so a String's memory footprint isn't limited to the number of characters being stored?